# Paypal get userinfo from refresh token

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5.4, paypal-rest-sdk

I have paypal refresh token stored on my server. and i want to get the user basic info like profile email using that refresh token.
but while trying to the get userinfo there are no such profile info.

```
$refreshToken = 'R23AAGKvPzMhDzJLohQ507s2NBBhP2lIS6m8BplqE_jEJpUGkiyjWEi-NJHC0omAh3n16N0x3_h4keLrANDFNOiLtWIho91Q5tpwqhRAJZJS4pYoOa9Psh4eYTIwdiIjcFVIMcDaaQPq1Ilb1R60w';

$tokenInfo = new OpenIdTokeninfo();
$tokenInfo = $tokenInfo->createFromRefreshToken(array('refresh_token'=> 
$refreshToken), $this->apiContext);
$params = array('access_token' => $tokenInfo->getAccessToken() );
$userInfo  = OpenIdUserinfo::getUserinfo($params, $this->apiContext);
dd($userInfo);
```

the resulted output is this

```
OpenIdUserinfo {#319
 -_propMap: array:1 [
 "user_id" => "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/identity/user/Lo-
 Qp2vr2KOQrIz4OOhWaj6XLEOj2TumkUfAArGKvwM"
 ]
```

I have generated the refreshtoken from the authetication code generated from MOBILE SDK
The transaction has to be done for Paypal Future Payment

The reference code used was https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/lipp/GetUserInfo.php